# Django database table naming convention

Tags: python, django, database, naming-conventions

What is the convention/best practices for naming database tables in Django... using the default database naming scheme (appname_classname) or creating your own table name (using your own naming conventions) with the meta class?

Comment: Why would the convention be anything other than the default?

Comment: @DanielRoseman You might want to use your own database naming convention... Django's isn't necessarily ideal. Or maybe you don't want to include the app name in your table name, or you want underscores to separate the words in your class name.

Answer (score 3):

The default convention is better and cleaner to use :

- It avoids any table naming conflict ( As It's a combination of App name and Model name)
- It creates well organized database (Tables are ordered by App names)

So until you have any special case that needs special naming convention , use the default.